# Mapping Array in a Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I passed the following props from a parent component to its child

**note**
*in the list of objects that this CardList component receives as props, **lang is an array which looks exactly like this `langs: ["React", "html", "CSS"]`** *

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from './Card';

function CardList ({jobs}) {
  return (
    jobs.map((job,i) => {
      return (
        <Card
          key={i}
          id={jobs[i].id}
          name={jobs[i].name}
          langs={jobs[i].langs} 
        />
     );
  );
}

export default CardList;
```

At the child component Card

```
import React from 'react';

function Card (props) {
  console.log(props.langs, typeof props.langs)
  return (
    <div>
      <p>props.id</p>
      <p>props.name</p>
      <ul>
        {
props.langs.map((lang, i) => {
  return (
    <li>
      {lang}
    </li>
  );
});
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

After rendering it say cannot map undefined

But it will log the props.langs and says it is type object when I use console.log

Comment: Why are you destructuring `{ jobs }` in `Card`? Change it to: `Card (props)`

Comment: There is much things wrong in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Card` component needs to destructure `id`, `name`, `langs` or use `props` directly like:

```js
import React from "react";

function Card(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.id}</p>
      <p>{props.name}</p>
      <ul>
        {props.langs.map((lang, i) => {
          return <li>{lang}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```